# Access Telegram-CLI by php

Tags: php, linux, composer-php, telegram, fedora-23

I want to access the [Telegram-CLI](https://github.com/vysheng/tg) using PHP.

I'm compiled Telegram-CLI and loged in to my account, and its works like a charm. 
 
I installed LAMP ([in Linux], Apache, MySQL, PHP) and i tested them works. 
 
I even installed these [following] PHP packages one-by-one using "Composer" and tested the examples but i couldnt make them run...

Also it seems their forum are abandoned to get my questions answer.

- [php-client for telegram-cli](https://github.com/zyberspace/php-telegram-cli-client)
- [A wrapper for Telegram-CLI](https://github.com/jlaso/telegram-cli-wrapper)
- [PHP Wrapper and Drupal module using Telegram CLI](https://github.com/josereyero/telegram)

I have no idea how the "Composer" works and how to make them work?

Could somebody tell me how to make one of them work in simple way.

**Edit:**
All steps of building Telegram-cli, loging in for first time and run it as deamon has beed completed.

[This project](https://github.com/zyberspace/php-telegram-cli-client) has been installed on php project root dir using "Composer".

Example.php file has been moved to web server root directory.
But also unning it cause a `500 Internal server error`.

The error line is:

```
$telegram = new \Zyberspace\Telegram\Cli\Client('unix:///tmp/tg.sck');
```

**notices:**
The file has been checked and is already there.

And the telegram-cli is running as a daemon on root user.

**Edit 2:**

I added a `telegramd` group and `telegramd` user assigned to that group.

I detacted that php commands running under `apache` user account.

I changed the `apache` user group to `telegramd`.

But again nothing...

So, Please help me